# Build fails due to architecture deprecation armv7 in Xcode 14

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, armv7, xcode14

I am trying to build and run my unity application in my iOS device for debugging purpose. I get a build file from Unity. Then I open .xcodeproj file in my xcode 14. When I run the app, it gives this error:

[image: error in my xcode 14 when I run the app]

When I google it, I find out that Xcode 14 does not support this architecture anymore:

[image: xcode 14 does not support armv7 arch]

So I cannot debug my unity app in my iOS device. You may say that okay use older version of Xcode like 13, however xcode 13 does not support iOS 16 or later (my device has iOS 16). I am little bit stuck in there.  How can I get rid of this situation? Is there any way to change the armv7 architecture that is created by unity build file?

I tried to solve armv7 error but I could not. Is there any way to handle this problem with unity and Xcode 14 environments?

Comment: Do you plan to release app to iOS 10 or lower ? BTW, the best thing is to update your ARCHS definition in build setting. The armv7 is for iPhone 5. Starting with iPhone 5S  it was arm64.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well and don't see a solution with Xcode 14.  I may have to investigate how to revert to Xcode 13 as I don't think I use any advanced iOS features and have older devices to test on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is an important question.  It's a perfectly clean question to me. If you want to support iOS 16.x, you have to use XCode 14 as I know of no way to add the iOS 16.x SDK to XCode 13.  Support for iOS 16.x is critical due to many changes in the way Apple changed rotation event handling.  If you want to support 32bit devices (all the way back to iPad 2), I know of no way to currently create a releasable binary that both includes iOS 16.x features AND 32 bit (armv7) at the same time.  If you try to compile an iOS 16.x app on XCode 13, you'll find too many SDK calls undefined.